# Does the pushforward $T_a(X)$ of a vector field $X$ on $M$ map to $T_a(X)$ again?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, tangent-spaces

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, $M$ be a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary and $X:M\to\mathbb R^d$ with $$X(a)\in T_a\:M\;\;\;\text{for all }a\in M\tag1.$$

> Let $a\in M$. By definition, the pushforward $T_a(X)$ is a map from $T_a\:M$ to $T_{X(a)}\mathbb R^d=\mathbb R^d$, but can we somehow show that it actually maps to $T_a\:M$?

Comment: Can you specify the question? Isn't it $T_aM$ at the end?

Comment: @Berci Yes, of course. Sorry.

Comment: It doesn't map there. Consider $M=S^1,\subseteq\Bbb R^2\cong\Bbb C$ and $X(z)=iz$.

Comment: @Berci I guess the "," is a typo, but I see (+1). Well, I actually didn't expect this to hold, but [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373398/91890) raised some doubts. Maybe you can take a look.